# Method deprecated authenticateWithCompletionHandler

Tags: ios, objective-c

I know, there are some threads about this, but I didn't really get what I excatly have to do for my class.

```
- (void)authenticateLocalUser {

if (!gameCenterAvailable) return;

NSLog(@"Authenticating local user...");
if ([GKLocalPlayer localPlayer].authenticated == NO) {
    [[GKLocalPlayer localPlayer]
     authenticateWithCompletionHandler:nil];
} else {
    NSLog(@"Already authenticated!");
}
}
```

How can I fix the problem, it says "authenticateWithCompletionHandler" is deprecated.

Can somebody help me out?

EDIT:

With the new code

```
- (void)authenticateLocalUser {

if (!gameCenterAvailable) return;

NSLog(@"Authenticating local user...");

if ([GKLocalPlayer localPlayer].authenticated == NO) {

    GKLocalPlayer *localPlayer = [GKLocalPlayer localPlayer];
    [localPlayer setAuthenticateHandler:(^(UIViewController* viewcontroller, NSError *error) {
        //[localPlayer authenticateWithCompletionHandler:^(NSError *error) { OLD CODE!
        if(localPlayer.isAuthenticated) {
            //do some stuff
        }else {
            // not logged in
        }
    })];
} else {
    NSLog(@"Already authenticated!");
}   
}
```

The error is : Capturing "localPlayer" strongly in this block is likely to lead to a retain circle . Its in the if(localPlayer.isAuthenticated).

also, the Game Center is not popping up anymore. If i want to let it pop up again with this code:

```
localPlayer.authenticateHandler = ^(UIViewController *viewController,NSError *error) {
if (localPlayer.authenticated) { 
//already authenticated
} else if(viewController) {
[self presentViewController:viewController];//present the login form
} else {
//problem with authentication,probably bc the user doesn't use Game    Center
} 
};
```

Same Error here.

Here as img:

[image]

Comment: As said by the doc: "Deprecation Statement Set the authenticateHandler property instead."

Comment: possible duplicate of [authenticateWithCompletionHandler: is deprecated: first deprecated in iOS 6.0](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14423995/authenticatewithcompletionhandler-is-deprecated-first-deprecated-in-ios-6-0)

Comment: authenticateWithCompletionHandler is deprecated in iOS6, you have to use setAuthenticateHandler (setAuthenticateHandler is new in iOS 6 )

Comment: I edited my post , have a look pls

Comment: Try the [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14423995/authenticatewithcompletionhandler-is-deprecated-first-deprecated-in-ios-6-0) at the link provided previously. You are creating the localPlayer within the completion block which you should not be doing. Here is a quick primer on [objc blocks](http://rypress.com/tutorials/objective-c/blocks)

Comment: I did exactly, but I get the error thats on the picture above

Comment: That's a new error, just looking for it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7205128/fix-warning-capturing-an-object-strongly-in-this-block-is-likely-to-lead-to-a

Comment: Make the variable __weak or __block.

Comment: yeah the __weak variable worked, im trying to add the game center login form when the user is not already logged in but its not working swell, look my comment unter the answer of Peppo

Comment: Considering the effort spent to fix this it might be worthwhile to update what worked for you. The code that resolved your problem may be useful to others and I noted the answer was not updated. Consider adding the solution to this question (especially if it is different from the prior asked question).

Comment: i posted what worked for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You replaced the method with this method:

```
-(void)authenticateLocalUser {


NSLog(@"Authenticating local user ...");
if(!gameCenterAvailable) {
    return;
}

    GKLocalPlayer *localPlayer = [GKLocalPlayer localPlayer];
    localPlayer.authenticateHandler = ^(UIViewController *viewController, NSError *error){
    NSLog(@"authenticateHandler");
    if (viewController != nil)
    {
        NSLog(@"viewController != nil");
    }
    else if (localPlayer.isAuthenticated)
    {
        NSLog(@"localPlayer already authenticated");
        //do some stuff
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"local player not authenticated");
        // not logged in
    }
   };
}
```

Comment: Or adapt this method to yours

Comment: You can add this "if" for safety:  (I edit my answer)

Comment: I did, but the warning is still there

Comment: The issue is that the localPlayer object is keeping a strong reference to itself, use __weak GKLocalPlayer *blockLocalPlayer = localPlayer;

Comment: That worked to me thanks! now , if the player is not logged in i want to show the login form like [self presentViewController:viewController]; but i get an error the selector presentViewController is not declared.

Comment: additional info: i made a class GKTurnBasedMatchHelper where i have the method in, its a subclass of NSObject

Comment: Do you know what I mean ? :(

Comment: Yes.....emmm.....I think that you can use : [self showAuthenticationDialogWhenReasonable: viewController];

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90621/discussion-between-robin-and-peppo).

Answer (score 0):

-(void)authenticateLocalUser {

```
if(!gameCenterAvailable) { return; }

GKLocalPlayer *localPlayer = [GKLocalPlayer localPlayer];
__weak GKLocalPlayer *blockLocalPlayer = localPlayer;

localPlayer.authenticateHandler = ^(UIViewController *viewController, NSError *error){
    NSLog(@"authenticateHandler");
    if (viewController != nil)
    {
        NSLog(@"viewController != nil");
    }
    else if (blockLocalPlayer.isAuthenticated)
    {
        NSLog(@"localPlayer already authenticated");
        //do some stuff
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"local player not authenticated");
        // not logged in
    }
};
```

}

this worked for me